# dynamic selectpicker shows undefined

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-selectpicker

[In this jsfiddle,](https://jsfiddle.net/3w9vghLu/) I'm dynamically adding options to `#type` which is a bootstrap select picker. Once that's populated, I am calling `getMenus()` which is using the ID attribute from `#type` to make another ajax call and populate values for the second select picker, `#filters`.

The first select populates fine, but the value is undefined. No matter what I do, I can't seem to get it to recognize the options in the select.

Once the page is loaded, if I change `#type`, then the change event is triggered and everything happens the way it should. It seems to only be affecting the first run of `getType()` when the page first loads. Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**
It looks like at least one problem is related to this line:

`$('#type').selectpicker('destroy').empty();`

If I remove the destroy method, the select will at least show up, but it's not populated with any options.

I added this to the init function and now it's working correctly:

```
$(document).on('loaded.bs.select', '#type', function(){
    getMenus();
    console.log('getMenus completed');
});
$(document).on('loaded.bs.select', '#and-filter-0', function(){
    getOperators();
    console.log('getMenus completed');
});
```

I'd like to know if this is the best possible method to make this work, and/or if there are any other problems that exist that I'm just coding around with the above solution.

Comment: Yes if  ('destroy').empty() is removed..then #type dropdown is getting filled... and also 2 options are getting inserted but not selected... let me debug it a little more

Answer (score 0):

You were close... The only reason it didn't worked because  **$('#type').append(options);** is getting called after **getMenus completed**

So the selection attribute was getting fired earlier because of the async nature. when you used the API provided **loaded.bs.select'** .it gave the correct call back

IF you want your JSfiddle Code to work you could use a promise.. I have used **async :false** as a temporary solution . [Check my Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m8v4bhza/)

All I did was

```
request = $.ajax({
      url: '/echo/json/',
      type: 'POST',
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      async : false,
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        json: JSON.stringify(json)
```

*So the conclusion is* .. Using the inbuilt **'loaded.bs.select'** event is the best possible solution ... There are ways of using promises here but it would make the code lengthy .. So you are on the right track